# Emulating non-US USB keyboard

Tags: arduino, keyboard, usb

I want to use a digispark as a USB keyboard, to easily log some data and messages into any open and active text window (e.g. notepad)
There's a sample demo  and libary from digistump, which works in general, but it assumes a US keyboard.

My PC runs with a German keyboard. 
No problem to switch y and z and to produce most other special characters on differnt keyboard locations. Also no problem to produce characters like { }, which require alt-gr key combinations with a german keyboard.

However, there's a key between the left shift key and the Y ( Z ) key, which produces < > | . This key does not exist on a US keyboard, so I cannot find out which USB code I should use for that key.

Question: Which is the USB code for that bottom left extra key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [HID Usage Tables 1.12](http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/Hut1_12v2.pdf):

> ```
> Usage ID (Dec) (Hex)   Usage Name  
>           100    64    Keyboard Non-US \ and | (notes 3;6)
> ```
>
> 3 Typical language mappings: Belg:<> FrCa:«°» Dan:<> Dutch:]|[ Fren:<> Ger:<|> Ital:<> LatAm:<> Nor:<> Span:<>
>   Swed:<|> Swiss:<> UK:\| Brazil: \|.
>
> 6 Typically near the Left-Shift key in AT-102 implementations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for both the link to the "USB - Bible" and for extracting the relevant lines :)